# PHP Session for login - doesn't recognise

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I'm writing a login code for my control panel for my website. I've made the login script. But for some reason the session doesn't save, here is the parts of my code I use:

index.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    require('scripts/validateLogin.php');
}

if($_SESSION['login'] == 1) {
    $loginOkay=1; 
    echo "Logged in";
} else {
    $loginOkay=0;
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

validateLogin.php

```
require('mysql_connect.php');

$username = htmlspecialchars(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$password = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username,password FROM tb_mods WHERE username = '$username';");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['login'] == 1;
    }
}
```

I call `session_start();` before I load my loginValidation.php so session_start(); is active in both pages.

I keep getting: Not logged in as result.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobbyt-ables.com), and your `htmlspecialchars()` is **UTTERLY** useless to protect you against such things. As well, why bother comparing usernames within the `while()` loop? The query will only return records with that username anyways, so you're wasting cpu cycles duplicating what the DB's already done for you.

Comment: I've written this code very quickly trying to get the functionality working first, after that I was planning on cleaning up my vulnerable code and cleaning up useless parts of the code. Right now I'm just stuck on the above issue. @MarcB

Comment: Is the query returning any data? I would also remove the while loop and count the results instead

Comment: May i ask what the loginOkay bool is ment to be ? try using a var_dump($_SESSION) and see what it returns!

Comment: In this bit `if($_SESSION['login'] == 1) {` I would also do `isset($_SESSION['login'])` as otherwise you will be getting error message that session is undefined. Plus there is no need to compare it to 1, as 1 is basically TRUE in a programming language so you could do `if ($_SESSION['login']) {....`

Comment: The loginOkay is used later on to decide if I should require login.php or can load the normal Control Panel. I've got it fixed though, I used index.php to create the session instead of the loginvalidator in a deeper folder and now it works :)

Comment: Thanks for all the advices, I got it solved since my session was created in 1 folder more down then my index.php was, so I used a variable to set in in the index.php and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the line $_SESSION['login'] == 1; is wrong, you need only one equal character to add value to the session variable. I hope it will help.